# ROS Fuerte Install on Gentoo fails at `rosdep install -a`

Tags: ros, installation, gentoo, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Fuerte Install on Gentoo fails at `rosdep install -a`

Following step by step the instructions from here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Gentoo

The following output is from `rosdep install -a` :

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rxtools: No definition of [swig-wx] for OS [gentoo]
image_geometry: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
bondcpp: No definition of [uuid] for OS [gentoo]
image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
rviz: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [gentoo]
image_view: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
cv_bridge: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
gazebo: No definition of [tbb] for OS [gentoo]
image_rotate: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
opencv2: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
stereo_image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
python_qt_binding: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [gentoo]
cv_markers: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
opende: No definition of [libx11] for OS [gentoo]
nodelet: No definition of [uuid] for OS [gentoo]
opencv_tests: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
turtlesim: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [gentoo]
pcl_ros: No definition of [pcl] for OS [gentoo]
depth_image_proc: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
camera_calibration: No definition of [opencv2] for OS [gentoo]
stage: No definition of [libjpeg] for OS [gentoo]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32872/ros-fuerte-install-on-gentoo-fails-at-%60rosdep-install--a%60/) by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2012-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created the needed package mappings (except for `swig-wx`, I have faked this with a mapping to `swig`), with a few added work arounds.

First change over to my rosdep mappings.

```
sed -i 's/ros/jmesmon/' /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
```

The repo can be found here: [github.com/jmesmon/rosdistro](https://github.com/jmesmon/rosdistro/)

Add the following overlay for `pcl`:

```
layman -a ezod
```

Then remove the dependency on ros from python_qt_binding. For some reason it is not resolved properly. Edit ~/ros/python_qt_binding/manifest.xml and delete

```
<rosdep name="ros" />
```

Without this edit, the following occurs (note that where-defined finds it just fine).

```
~/g/rosdistro/rosdep $ rosdep install -a
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
python_qt_binding: No definition of [ros] for OS [gentoo]

~/g/rosdistro/rosdep $ rosdep where-defined ros
https://github.com/jmesmon/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
```

With these changes, this step completes succesfuly.

```
~/g/rosdistro/rosdep $ rosdep install -a
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

---

Originally posted by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) with karma: 125 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-05-16**:
Looks like the pcl from the ezod repo doesn't work with ROS. Need to create a custom package for a patched version. Why can't rosdep just build and install gbp repos itself? Also note that I've removed the PCL and swig-wx mappings, so the above won't work flawlessly.

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2012-07-02**:
Please, submit a pull request if you haven't. It will avoid to other Gentoo users to duplicate this work :)

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-07-15**:
I submitted a pull request: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/42, but the issue with pcl still stands. As does the lack of actual swig-wx bindings. On pcl: a patched version is uneeded, but an option needs to be passed to pcl's cmake to use the ros bindings.

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-07-15**:
What we really need is for rosdep to not fail when it can't find something. Or a way to manually tell it something was installed. ie: portage's "provided". Issue here: https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/15  and here: https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/16

**Comment by [Cody](https://answers.ros.org/users/1588/cody/) on 2012-07-15**:
I'm not actively involved in any projects using ROS at the moment, so it is unlikely I'll be the one working on this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello :) It took me nearly one full day but I can offer you a solution :D

First at all (as hint) Fuerte and/or rosdep 2 does not look anymore in any rosdep.yaml file !!! (sry I have already closed that link)

I've worked it out with the following steps:

1. I've downloaded the base.yaml and gentoo.yaml files (which you can easily find if you look into /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list)
2. modify the gentoo.yaml file with your needed expressions like for libjpeg:
   libjpeg:
   gentoo:
   portage:
   packages: jpeg
   3.Copy the files to your own webserver or any other place in the web
3. then modify the /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list to link to your modified files
4. make a rosdep update to take the changes and gratulations
5. now it will find the defined gentoo files :D

Hopefully it works for you as well :)

Bye,
SIegfried

---

Originally posted by [Beresford](https://answers.ros.org/users/2331/beresford/) with karma: 11 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1